# Is it possible to attach a file from Google Documents to an email by Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-drive

Is it possible to attach a file already in my Google Documents account to an email written in Gmail, without downloading it?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Google Docs Gadget that can be enabled in Settings/Labs.

> Adds a box in the left column which displays your Google Docs. Shows recent docs, starred docs, and has fast search.

You can drag the document into the message

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. What file types can be used?

Answer (score 2):

I have only been able to email Google Docs directly from the Docs interface instead of starting in Gmail. There is no download required if you go this route.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail now lets you [insert multiple files from Drive/Google Docs directly into an email without leaving your Gmail](http://gmailblog.blogspot.in/2012/11/gmail-and-drive-new-way-to-send-files.html).